# How to upload an Image to Firebase Storage using Kotlin in Android Q

Tags: firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage

I have tried the older Method
var bitmap =MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap() which is now depricated and I Surfed the web and did not find a satisfactory Method.Please Any Suggest a Method to Upload an Image to Firebase Storage.

Comment: You don't need a bitmap to upload an image to Storage. Image uri is enough for you.

Comment: for displaying it You need an Bitmap and to pick it from Gallery .which is now depricated .Please try to understand the  Statements and methods Before Giving Negetive Pops.

Comment: Don't need. You are getting image uri from gallery not bitmap. If you want you can convert uri to bitmap. So you need uri to upload to storage. I didn't give negative vote

Answer (score 6):

Select image from gallery fun like this:

```
private fun selectImageFromGallery() {

val intent = Intent()
intent.type = "image/*"
intent.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
startActivityForResult(
        Intent.createChooser(
            intent,
            "Please select..."
        ),
        GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE
    )
}
```

onActivityResult like this:

```
override fun onActivityResult(
    requestCode: Int,
    resultCode: Int,
    data: Intent?
) {

    super.onActivityResult(
        requestCode,
        resultCode,
        data
    )

    if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST_CODE
        && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK
        && data != null
        && data.data != null
    ) {

        // Get the Uri of data
        val file_uri = data.data
        uploadImageToFirebase(file_uri)
    }
 }
```

upload image :

```
private fun uploadImageToFirebase(fileUri: Uri) {
if (fileUri != null) {
val fileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString() +".jpg"

val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
val refStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().reference.child("images/$fileName")

refStorage.putFile(fileUri)
    .addOnSuccessListener(
        OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> { taskSnapshot ->
            taskSnapshot.storage.downloadUrl.addOnSuccessListener {
                val imageUrl = it.toString()
            }
        })

    ?.addOnFailureListener(OnFailureListener { e ->
        print(e.message)
    })
  }
}
```

**As you can see , you don't need any bitmaps**

Comment: Man thx for help ....I Understand your code but i am Stucked at val fileName = UUID.randomUUID().toString() +".jpg" .what Uuid.random is doing here and why it is used here

Comment: Your Code Did Not Work

Comment: imageUrl is never Used so How You Implemeted this

Comment: I am using a unique name before uploading. You can change this place as you wish.

Comment: If you want, you can save the imageUrl to Firebase Database. I showed you how you uploaded the url of an image.

Comment: What is the problem? Did you add permission?